# Numpy array If I request too much length initially, can I efficiently reduce the length and free up the excess memory later?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm guessing 6,000 elements will be used. Actually, only 1,000 elements are used.is there any other efficient and low memory usage way to reduce the length of the array?

That's what I can think of, but not sure it works? Looking forward to any better methods！

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.empty(6000)
arr = arr[:1000]
```

Answer (score -1):

The original array with 6000 elements still exists in memory until it is explicitly deleted or goes out of scope. To free up the memory occupied by the original array, you can use the del statement to delete the reference to it. Here's an example:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.empty(6000)
arr = arr[:1000]

# Delete the original array to free up memory
del arr
```

After executing the del arr statement, the memory occupied by the original 6000 element array will be released.

Alternatively, if you want to modify the array in-place without creating a new array, you can use the resize method of the NumPy array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.empty(6000)
arr.resize(1000)
```

Now arr has been resized in-place to contain only the first 1000 elements
This way, you modify the existing array without creating a new one, which can be more memory-efficient if you don't need the original array anymore.

Comment: You probably meant `arr2 = arr[:1000]`. Your current code is deleting everything.